# Object.assign does not copy correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with VueJS.

I have a Method that receives a Object as argument.

Then I clone this Object with `Object.assign()`.

```
Component.vue

export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    // ...
    activateEditMode (item) {
      this.editItemIndex = this.travelItinerary.indexOf(item)
      this.editItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

The original Object at `this.roteiroCompleto[0]`:

[image]

But when I edit the clone Object `this.itemEditado`:

[image]

the original Object `this.roteiroCompleto[0]` changes too.

[image]

I tried to copy each key and value, copy only the Array with `.slice()`, `.map(a=>a)`, and nothing works. The two objects keep binding.

When I `console.log(this.itemEditado)`, I get this:

[image]

The strange thing is, in another Vue Component, I use the same strategy, and it works.

Comment: Maybe you should update the answer to Martins answer where it's using structuredClone

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Object.assign` only does a shallow copy of the keys and values, meaning if one of the values in the object is another object or an array, then it is the same reference as was on the original object.

```
var x = { a: 10, b: { c: 100 } };
var y = Object.assign({}, x);

y.a = 20;
console.log( x.a, y.a ); // prints 10 20

y.b.c = 200;
console.log( x.b.c, y.b.c ) // prints 200 200
```

To deep copy an object, you can using something like the [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) function in lodash or take an uglier approach using built in functions with `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( obj ) )`.

Note that the second option will only work with primitive types that are supported by JSON.

Comment: Thank you, Garret! I installed the `cloneDeep` function with `npm install --save lodash.clonedeep` and imported it within my Component. Now it works fine!

Comment: lodash is too big.  Not worth.  Just write a  constructor taking json as arg

Answer (score 6):

If the methods you used isn't working well with objects involving data types, try this

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Deep clone object

```
myObjCopy = _.cloneDeep(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone)

```js
 Object.assign(this.editItem, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, to deep clone objects natively on JavaScript you can use **structuredClone**

> The global structuredClone() method creates a deep clone of a given
> value using the structured clone algorithm.

[MDN structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to use a library, unless you really need a deep copy (I did not need one). Just do this:

```
this.editItem = {...item};
```

The `...` operator will decompose `item` into its keys and values, and since you're doing that in an object literal (the `{ }`), it uses those as the keys and values of the new object.

Might be helpful to other people who, like me, don't need a deep copy. `Object.assign` just straight-up doesn't work, and this does.

Comment: `{ ...item }` is the same as `Object.assign( {}, item )` and are therefore both just shallow copies. If the spread operator worked but Object.assign did not then something else must have changed about your code, as well.

Comment: "Object.assign just straight-up doesn't work" This is just not true

Comment: Spread copy does a shallow copy, not a deep one.

Comment: @letie Right, that's what I said. If you need a deep copy, try a library or `this.editItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))`.