# How to do object assign but create new copies of arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
        this.data_table.editedIndex = this.data_table.items.indexOf(item);
        this.data_table.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
        this.data_table.edit.tabs.currentTab = 0;
        this.data_table.dialog = true;
```

but i'm noticing an issue where when the `item` has an array, i think the same array gets put in the new object. How can I change it so that it makes a new copy of the array? Preferably a deep copy of the array.

Comment: Try using `item.slice(0)`. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array

Comment: item is an object, just one of its properties is an array

Comment: @YaakovAinspan: that won't deep clone the array, i.e., you will get a new array but it will still refer to the same objects as the original array. A deep clone of the array might look like: `var newArray = item.theArray.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));`. This basically does what OP is doing for the main object but applying it to the array as well. The problem is that I don't know of a one-liner, you might have to write a helper method.

Comment: also, the item is arbitrary so I can't hardcode its properties name.

Comment: is stringify, and parse the best option?

Comment: @omega either that or lodash.cloneDeep, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50520945/963881

Comment: @omega:Certainly a valid solution. Might have a little extra overhead but it would cover all the strange cases you might run inot.

Comment: can you use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Object.assign` create a helper method to iterate through the object, determine if a value is an array and explicitly copy it using a `spread operator ( ... )`

```
   let copyObj = o => {
      let new_o = {};
      for (let k of Object.keys(o)) {
        (Array.isArray(o[k])) ? new_o[k] = [...o[k]]: new_o[k] = o[k];
      }
      return new_o;
    }
```

```js
//create copy function
let copyObj = o => {
  let new_o = {};
  for (let k of Object.keys(o)) {
    (Array.isArray(o[k])) ? new_o[k] = [...o[k]]: new_o[k] = o[k];
  }
  return new_o;
},

//our object
obj = {
  aString: "hola!",
  anArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
},

//our new object
nObj = copyObj(obj);

//change the old object
obj.anArray[3] = 555555;

//the old object array is changed, but the new one isn't.
console.log("new object: ", nObj, "old object: ", obj);
```

**Note** to deep clone the Array and return entirely new Objects and Arrays from within the first level of the Array or deeper, you would implement this same technique with further conditionals and recursively call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash will do the trick. Try method `_.merge(obj1, obj2)`
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge

> Array and plain object properties are merged recursively.