# Dialog maintains changed values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a component which displays a users name and email address. I open a new dialog which enables the user to edit the name and email. The user data for the edit dialog is passed in as a prop to the dialog. The edit text fields of the dialog already have the current user name/email pre filled for editing. When a user edits the name but clicks cancel on the dialog then opens the dialog again the change is still there. It doesn't seem to be taking in the value passed as a prop? How can I fix this?

```
  <template>

 <div>

    <v-dialog v-model="EditDialog" persistent max-width="400px" >

          <Dialog :user="user"  height="400px"   />
        </v-dialog>

  <other stuff on page>
</div>
</template>
```

Dialog

```
 <v-text-field
    label="Name"
   v-model="user.name"

  filled
    placeholder="Name"
  ></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the props that will to be edited in the dialog into the dialog **data** section just before opening the dialog.
2. Use copied props for editing (bind them to your editor components).
3. Copy edited props back to the original ones after the dialog confirmation is made.

Comment: @Anatoly- how do I copy the props?

Comment: For instance: const propsCopy = Object.assign({}, originalProps). If you wish to create a copy of all nested props you can use something like lodash package and its method cloneDeep

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements.

--from the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)

Basically, instead of updating the variable value only when explicitly assigned, as is common, `v-model` automatically updates at the root instance as data is modified. To understand what this means practically, if you watch `user.name` in the Vue tab in dev tools, you'll see that it is assigned the string as the user is typing it into the text field. By the time the user clicks `cancel`, the entered data is already saved and it doesn't revert.

So how unwanted changes be canceled?

Simply create a data cache before making any changes, and use it to revert the data when `cancel` is called.

For example, after data is pulled in from a database:

```
.then(() => (this.dataCache = Object.assign({}, this.user)));
```

having created `dataCache: {}` as an empty object in the `data` hook.

Then something like:

```
$on('cancelUserChanges', () => {
    this.user = Object.assign({}, this.dataCache;
});
```

---

Note that in using this fix with arrays you may run up against problems because

> Object.assign only does a shallow copy of the keys and values, meaning
> if one of the values in the object is another object or an array, then
> it is the same reference as was on the original object.

--from @GarrettJohnson 's answer to [object assign does not copy correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520832/object-assign-does-not-copy-correctly)

To get round this issue by deep cloning the object, as stated in that answer, you can use something like lodash's [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) function or `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( obj ) )` (which will however only work with primitive types that are supported by JSON).